# UISwitch too slow when forceRightToLeft

Tags: swift, uikit, togglebutton, uiswitch, toggleswitch

My app uses English and Arabic languages.

I have this in my AppDelegate:

```
if isArabic {
    UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
}
```

When `Arabic(forces elements to go right-to-left)`, all UI elements seem to work fine, except `UISwiftch`.
It works but it is too slow, it toggles, then after one or two seconds it changes its color depending on `ON/OFF State`.
No more code for UISwitch except this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!
```

, so I don't know what causes this weird issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix I have found:
Even if whole app is forced right-to-left on Arabic, I force left-to-right my UISwitch. You can do it in `viewDidLoad`

```
mySwitch.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

On is still On, Off is still Off, everything works, the UISwitch is on the left side of the screen because the whole screen is forced to left when Arabic, that is also fine. The only difference now is that the `On` state is active when you swipe toggle left(like in English), not right. But thats almost insensibly and none notices the "hack" :)

Answer (score 0):

In case one prefer to go code-less using storyboard just need to change the Semantic property in the Attribute inspector of the Switch (or any view since it's a UIView property)

[image]